# unable to access nav_header_main.xml

Tags: android

Can anyone help me to sort the problem, i did everything to access them in my code

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private ImageView mDisplayImageView;
private TextView mNameTextView;
private TextView mEmailTextView;

NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
 View navHeaderView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
 initNavHeader(navHeaderView);
}
private void initNavHeader(View view) {
mDisplayImageView = (ImageView) 
view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_display);
mNameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_name);
mEmailTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_email);
}
```

Comment: Where is nav_header_main.xml?

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: @JohnJoe should i upload this as well ??

Comment: @NabEelKambOh Your question is quite unclear. You said unable to access nav_header_main.xml, but there are no unable to access nav_header_main.xml in your code.

Comment: @JohnJoe i want to access my image view from nav_header_main.xml but it is not accessing at all

Comment: @JohnJoe https://gist.github.com/nabeelnazir163/6217f6e049add3fc9b73c514d51488ea check this out

Comment: Can't help , I never work with NavigationView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use onnavigationitem selected method like this...
firast of all define navigation view in create method..

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_frag1);
```

then create method...

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        logo=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo);
        logo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Unable to get Permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        int id = item.getItemId();
        fragment = null;

        if (id == R.id.nav_frag1) {
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
        }
        /*else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }*/

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nabeelnazir163/6217f6e049add3fc9b73c514d51488ea @Nilesh Check gist

Comment: @DevyaniKotadiya yeah Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

**try this you can access image and textview of your** `nav_header_main.xml` like this

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);       

mNameTextView = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.textview_name);
mEmailTextView = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.textView_email);
mDisplayImageView = (ImageView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.imageView_display);
```

Comment: Checl gist https://gist.github.com/nabeelnazir163/6217f6e049add3fc9b73c514d51488ea

Comment: @NabEelKambOh can u expalin what is the problem